# If Statement Alternative (Conditional Operator)

Tags: c++

I keep getting a syntax error when trying to compile the following:

```
template <class Type>
Type larger(Type x, Type y)
{
    return (x >= y) ? x : y);
}
```

I am used to the normal if-else statements but I was trying to get some practice with this format. Any idea where I went wrong?

Comment: You might want to use const references here, to avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: Was the text of the error message really of *no* help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra `)` at the end of the return statement :

```
return (x >= y) ? x : y);
```

should be :

```
return (x >= y) ? x : y;
```

Comment: Please note that [close] vote now includes a specific category for questions with syntax errors.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : if the question is considered off-topic due to a typo (which is what I assume you were referring to), then it could be appropriate to close it, yes. I'm not sure why you're telling me though - do you mean we're not allowed to help people with their off-topic questions ? Surely both answering the question and closing it afterwards serves everyone's needs ?

Comment: Answering off-topic questions begets more off-topic questions.

Comment: Providing help is what this site is about. However, site's visibility being high, it's a good idea to think about answering questions in long-term perspective. Few years ago there was no specific category for closing syntax error and typo questions, so the site has accumulated a great deal of them. Answering such questions makes them hard to delete, so they pollute the search space forever. Consider this particular question as an example: on the surface, it is about a conditional expression, but in reality it is about something else, making the search for the right answer more difficult.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : I get that, but it's my understanding that closing a question also de-indexes it so it doesn't pollute search results (hence my earlier remark on serving everyone's needs). If this is not what's actually happening, then maybe it should. In any case, in order not to rustle any more feathers, I'll delete this answer once this discussion is concluded - I achieved my goal of helping the OP with his problem, and that's all I set out to do.

Comment: Turns out I can't delete an accepted answer ...